# Confusion in SOP and POS form

Tags: boolean-algebra

Given

```
x’ + x(x + y’)(y + z’)
```

Turn it into SOP and POS form (not the Canonical ones) and without using a K-map

I have done as follows;

```
    = x’ + x(x + y’)(y + z’)
    = x’ + (x + xy’)(y+z’)
    = x’ + xy’z’+ xyy’ + xz’ + xy
    = x’ + xy’z’ + xz’ + xy
    = x’ + xz’(y’+1) + xy
    = x’ + xz’ + xy
    = (x’ + x)(x’ + z’) + xy
    = x’ + z’ + xy
    = (x’ + x)(x’ + y) + z’
    = x’ + y + z’
```

Now is `x’ + y + z’`  both the SOP and POS form of the given? Or should I have stopped midway and did another approach?

Comment: I think it's right and it's the best solution here.

Comment: I see. I'm just a little bit confused as most of the materials always give an example of e.g. `x + yz` as an SOP as it is a sum of product/s and some such as `z(x+y)` for a POS

Comment: So I could just see this in this way: in SOP as if they are products of 1 and in POS as if the whole `(x' + y + z')` is a product of 1 so hence a product of sums as well

Comment: You used the De Morgan's laws very well.

Answer (score 2):

You did everything correctly, and yes, the final form is both in SOP and POS, but here are two very useful principles that will make your boolean-algebra-life a lot easier:

**Absorption**

$x + xy = x$

and its dual:

$x(x+y)=x$

**Reduction**

$x+x'y=x+y$

and its dual:

$x(x'+y)=xy$

With those:

$x'+x(x+y')(y+z')\overset{Absorption}{=}$

$x'+x(y+z')\overset{Reduction}{=}$

$x'+y+z'$

Done!